# Docking in wpf .net 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, docking

is there a built in possibility in .net 4.0 to dock a WPF window into a container?? Something like in Visual Studio would be great.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/ is an open-source docking solution... works nicely in .net4